# What is the children's book about a troll looking for a rope to hang his brother?

Tags: identification-request

There is a book I remember from the 1980s (but I had older siblings, so it may have been a decade earlier) that followed the structure of "the house that jack built" but was about 2 brothers that may have been trolls. I think one brother stole berries or maybe a pie from the other, so he was trying to get a rope to hang him. He goes to get the rope, but has to get something else first, and then that sends him to something else and at the end he decides not to hang his brother. Each page repeated and built upon the previous one. The brothers' names were something like Munchin.

Comment: This is called a cumulative/chain tale, if helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it after it was featured on the Myths and Legends podcast. It is a Celtic story called Munachar and Manachar and the picture book I remember was by Riley Smith. Here is a link to the text of the story if anyone else comes searching... it's even worse than I remembered:
https://sacred-texts.com/neu/celt/cft/cft13.htm

And the podcast that solved the mystery:

[https://www.mythpodcast.com/category/mythpodcast/episodes/#:~:text=Munachar%20and%20Manachar%20are%20two,re%20making%20%5B...%5D](https://www.mythpodcast.com/category/mythpodcast/episodes/#:%7E:text=Munachar%20and%20Manachar%20are%20two,re%20making%20%5B...%5D)